# Google in-app payments: howto to handle Google's postback JWT

Tags: php, postback, jwt

Maybe its a stupid question but I'm not an advanced programmer. I've 
have successfully setup In-App payments for my app but it only works 
without using a postback url.

I've Google'd around many hours trying to tackle this myself without 
success. Hopefully anybody could help me out. I've included the script 
handling the post data which does obviously something wrong.. This is what Google says:

> Your server must send a 200 OK response for each HTTP POST message
>   that Google sends to your postback URL. To send this response, your
>   server must:
>
> Decode the JWT that's specified in the jwt parameter of the POST
>   message. Check to make sure that the order is OK. Get the value of the
>   JWT's "orderId" field. Send a 200 OK response that has only one thing
>   in the body: the "orderId" value you got in step 3.

This is what I wrote but as far as I can see there is no way to test it (how can I simulate a post from Google?).

```
require_once 'include/jwt.php'; // including luciferous jwt library 

$encoded_jwt = $_POST['jwt']; 
$decoded_jwt = JWT::decode($encoded_jwt, "fdNAbAdfkCDakJQBdViErg"); 
$decoded_jwt_array = (array) $decoded_jwt; 
$orderId = $decoded_jwt_array['response']['orderId']; 

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK"); 
echo $orderId;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem a year later and solved it with the following code:

```
require_once 'include/jwt.php'; // including luciferous jwt library 

$encoded_jwt = $_POST['jwt']; 
$decodedJWT = JWT::decode($jwt, $sellerSecret);

// get orderId
$orderId = $decodedJWT->response->orderId;

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK"); 
echo $orderId;
```

Google Wallet's In App Purchase documentation is relatively new, and lacking on the callback side. This code works both sandbox and production side, just make sure you use your own seller secret.

Comment: The above code worked for me. There is a more complete example with error checking (in Python) provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/training/getting-started/handle-notif

Answer (score -2):

Set Sandbox Postback URL in your Google Wallet setting to a test page, then log the requests to that page. You will see a JWT. Use it for test.