# Google Wallet sandbox purchases not showing up in merchant transactions

Tags: php, sandbox, android-pay

My transactions appear to complete client side yet the orders will not appear within the Sandbox's administration ([wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/manage](http://wallet-web.sandbox.google.com/manage)) -> transactions page. The test buyer account however gets a confirmation email.

I am sending everything according to the docs by returning a 200 OK and print_r'ing the order id. Any advice will be appreciated!

```
require_once('JWT.php');           // including luciferous jwt library 
require_once('seller_info.php');   // include seller info

$sellerSecret = SellerInfo::$secretKey;

// From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11225015/270712
$response = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ?                                            
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : file_get_contents("php://input");
$response = substr_replace($response, "", 0, 4);                      
$response = JWT::decode($response, $sellerSecret);

print_r($response->response->orderId);
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
```

Comment: Any errors on the client side callback?

Comment: No sir, no errors within the console and have not built my callbacks yet. Any advice there would be appreciated.