# Google Wallet Postback url email, pretty format JWT response in stdClass Object PHP for email

Tags: php, postback, html-email, android-pay, jwt

How do I make this text format from JWT Response in PHP Object into a nice print_r format in HTML.

I've tried

```
    //Pretty format plain-text to HTML.
    $message = preg_replace("\n\r?\n", "</p><p>", htmlspecialchars($message));
```

as it was suggested in another plain-text to HTML converstion topic here on stackoverflow. It completely doesn't return anything to $message and send's a empty body in the email.

Here is the current code:

```
<?php
    require_once ('myprivatekeys.php');
    //JWT class to encode/decode payload into JWT format. */
    include_once "googlecheckout/JWT.php";

    // From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11225015/270712
    $response = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ?
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : file_get_contents("php://input");
    $response = substr_replace($response, "", 0, 4);   //remove "jwt=" from raw http data
    $response = JWT::decode($response, $MerchantSecretKey);
    print_r($response->response->orderId);

    $subject = "Google Order Transaction waiting to be charged!";
    $message = print_r($response, true);
    $message .= "<br><B>Google Order waiting to be charged.</B>";

    //Pretty format plain-text to HTML.
    $message = preg_replace("\n\r?\n", "</p><p>", htmlspecialchars($message));

    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    // More headers
    $headers .= "From: <GoogleSales@website.com>\r\n";
    // send mail
    mail($emailTo,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Here is how the email currently is on a successful order in Google Wallet.

```
stdClass Object ( [iss] => Google [request] => stdClass Object ( [description] => Private [name] => Buy 2123 [price] => 1592.25 [currencyCode] => USD ) [response] => stdClass Object ( [orderId] => GWDG_S.c2b69e16-30a0-4578-ab6c-b89acb1fc9bf ) [typ] => google/payments/inapp/item/v1/postback/buy [aud] => 04183051302638724136 [iat] => 1404407507 [exp] => 1404407527 )
```

**Google Order waiting to be charged.**

Okay you can't visualize it here in this question i'll post a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

P.S.> If there is nothing I can do in 1 line I'll end up doing like,

(**I don't want to take this path since it's dangerous the variables could change at any time and I will lose orders due to merchant server errors !!!**)

Is there a way to iterate the whole JWT response for all variables and loop them somehow?

```
$message .="currencyCode => ". $response->currencyCode . "<BR>";
$message .="Typ => ". $response->response->typ. "<BR>";
etc.. etc..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it and learned a new HTML command `<pre>` (**Stands for Pre-Formatted Text**) probably alot of you guys don't know about this one but if you toss that tag in it renders plain-text as HTML in any modern browser probably one of the new features of HTML5 Hahah, I guess I get what I deserve not reading those changelogs.

FIXED CODE:

```
$message .=  "<pre>".print_r($response, true)."</pre>";
```